# Remove outer list from list of list in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a requirement in which I want to pass a set of lists separated by comma to a function.

```
searchTerms = ["a", "c", "d"]

stringList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a']

d = dict()

for j in range(len(searchTerms)):

    for i in range(len(stringList)):

        if searchTerms[j] == stringList[i]:

            d.setdefault(j, []).append(i)

print d.values()
```

if you run the above code the output will be `[[0, 4], [2], [3]]` but i need to pass `[0, 4], [2], [3]` to a function. Could anyone tell me how can I remove the outer list from here.

In short convert `[[0, 4], [2], [3]]` `------>` `[0, 4], [2], [3]`. Thanks

I want to send it to this function:

```
 for element in itertools.product([0, 4], [2], [3]):

    sortedList = sorted(list(element))
```

Comment: Have you tried `(x,y,z) = d.values()` and then passing x,y,z into your function?

Comment: See my edited question. I have added the function as well. I can't embed those values, I need to pass it. I want to store `[0, 4], [2], [3]` somewhere and then pass it. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
*[[0, 4], [2], [3]]
```

Hope it helps!

---

Example:

```
>>> def f(a, b, c):
...    print(a, b, c)
...
>>> f(*[1, 2, 3])
1 2 3
```

In your case:

```
for element in itertools.product(*d.values()):
    sortedList = sorted(list(element))
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more?

Comment: @RakeshRanjanSukla See the example.

Comment: Is it possible to store `[0, 4], [2], [3]` somewhere and then pass it? Because the number of parameters will be dynamic here. I have added the function as well in my question but that will take dynamic parameters.

Comment: @RakeshRanjanSukla You can only store those arguments as a list or tuple. Whenever you need to pass them to a function, use `f(*args)`.

Comment: Accepted your answer :) Thank you so much